# Fusion 360 animation , contact sets

Tags: mechanical

I was designing a whit-worth quick return mechanism, I have provided the contact sets but they fail when I try to animate. The contact set is defined for the crank and slotted link.

[image: the crank just rotates passing through the slotted link.]

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid joints created in the editor don't transfer to the Animation module. You have to animate the components again.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a contact set and not joints?   The common advice is to try to avoid contact sets since they are computationally expensive. Only use them in certain situations like proofing or fine tuning a contact.

If this is still relevant, can you share the design so it's easier to help?